# POSTGRESQL: Function result with Concat value

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create function with result of concatenated value.

see below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_name()
RETURNS TABLE(name text ) AS
$BODY$

BEGIN
RETURN QUERY 

select
cast(first_name as text)  ||' ' ||   cast( middle_name as text)  ||' ' || cast(last_name   as text) as name 
from table_name;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100
ROWS 1000;
```

However upon querying

```
 select * from select_name();
```

it shows error:

```
ERROR:  relation "select_name" does not exist
LINE 8: select * from select_name
                  ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "select_name" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 159
```

I'm stuck here. 
Please help.

Comment: Your function works for me... The error message looks like the parentheses were left out in the query. I am also suspicious about `LINE 8` and `Character: 159`. Maybe you omitted some detail that would clarify the problem. By the way: `'firstname' || NULL IS NULL`.

Comment: I agree with Laurenz: it seems you forgot to use `()` and just ran `select * from select_name`. Unrelated, but: your expression in the function can be simplified to `select concat_ws(' ', first_name, middle_name, last_name) as name` to properly deal with `null` values (Plus: you don't need PL/pgSQL for this, a plain SQL function will be enough)

Comment: Thanks all. :) i reviewed it again and made some adjustment, and it worked! I used this:    `cast(first_name  ||' ' ||  middle_name ||' ' ||  last_name as text) as name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to used below statement, and it worked. ^_^

```
select
 cast( first_name ||' ' || middle_name ||' ' ||  last_name as text) as  name
from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out this will go like a fly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_name()
RETURNS TABLE(name text ) AS
$$

BEGIN
RETURN QUERY 

select
select
cast(first_name as text)  ||' ' ||   cast( middle_name as text)  ||' ' || cast(last_name   as text) as name 
from table_name;

        END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```